# Is there a better way than this to stop a DBgrid flickering with time consuming updates?

Tags: mysql, delphi, tdbgrid

Can anyone offer advice on how to achieve what I want in the situation below?
(I wonder whether theads might help but haven't used them before.)

In my Delphi application I have a query running against an external MYSQL database over the Internet.The results of the query is shown in a DBGrid (at most 50 rows).

The user clicks a button to do a 'web check', then the following happens...

- First I set one field of the dataset (web_response) to the empty string to clear out any existing data showing there in the DBGrid.
- Then for each row in the dataset I extract the value of one field (FieldA), pass it to a function, and set the value of another field (web_response) to the result of that function.
- The function itself uses IdHTTP to perform a search on a different remote web site using the parameter passed and returns a response string. That process takes around 1 to 2s.

The effect I want is for the grid to have all the web response fields 'instantaneously' cleared, then row by row the web response field gets set to a value, with each value appearing as it is set.

The code below works correctly but does not quite give the effect I need . I'm wondering if using threads somewhere - instead of application.processmessages might improve things.

The effect I get at the moment is the grid goes completely blank for a second or two and then reappears with the web response column blank.
Then the rows get updated with the web response at about the rate of one row every 1s but with the grid flickering violently each time a new response is added. 
If threads won't help, is there a better way to do what I am doing?

**The code I use at the moment (with identifiers changed to protect the innocent)**

```
//empty any preexisting web responses
//disable controls to stop the DBgrid flickering while we clear out existing web responses
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  MyQuery1.Edit;
  MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := '';
  MyQuery1.Next;
end;
DBGrid1.RefreshData; //show cleared grid again
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls; 

 //For each row, check FieldA on the web and show response
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  DataToCheck := MyQuery1.FieldByName('FieldA').AsString ; //get data to check
  //get the web response and put into dataset
  MyQuery1.Edit;
  MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := GetWebCheckResponse(DataToCheck);
  Application.ProcessMessages; //,'cos the loop is slow <<-- can I get rid of this and use threads?
  DBGrid1.RefreshData; //show the response we just put in dataset
  MyQuery1.Next;
end;
```

Comment: BTW I tried replacing the first loop with executing the SQL statement
UPDATE Table SET web_response = '' where TheRowID = <the one the grid is showing>
eg
    DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls; 
    MyCommand1.ExecuteSQL;
    DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls; 
 
 but it made little difference.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing a MyQuery1.Post after editing its data.  Why?

Comment: if you're using `Application.ProcessMessages` you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MartynA Because I then move to the next row in the dataset. That does an implicit post and puts it in the database

Comment: @Peter Vonca Yes, I guessed that as I've heard lots of people saying Application.processmessages is the worse thing since GOTO but (a) here I have a time consuming loop and its there to stop the window freezing and to allow the grid to get its refresh message and (b) That was really the point of my post (see the comment against that line in the code). If you can explain how to do this a better way, possibly using threads, then that's what I would like to know.

Comment: Run the db code in a thread. When each new row is ready, send the data to the main thread for display.

Comment: Ah.  I've always avoided relying on implicit posts because they can make traps for the unwary.  E.g. ISTR that changes made in the OnNewRecord event may get discarded because they don't result in the record being marked as modified.

Comment: @user3209752, there are hundreds of SO questions related to this subject and most of them explain why you shouldn't use ProcessMessages and what you should use instead, it's just a matter of taking the time to do your research before posting a question that has already been answered so many times.

Answer (score 3):

Been more than 7 years since I last touched Delphi and we were not allowed to use data aware components so I might be giving you wrong advise here. However it appears that you are refreshing the grid too often. Especially you are refreshing the grid in a loop.

I would suggest changing the code to this:

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  MyQuery1.Edit;
  MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := '';
  MyQuery1.Next;
end;



//For each row, check FieldA on the web and show response
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
   DataToCheck := MyQuery1.FieldByName('FieldA').AsString ; //get data to check
   //get the web response and put into dataset
   MyQuery1.Edit;
   MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := GetWebCheckResponse(DataToCheck);
   Application.ProcessMessages; //,'cos the loop is slow <<-- can I get rid of this and use    threads?

   MyQuery1.Next;
end;
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls; 
DBGrid1.RefreshData; //show the response we just put in dataset
```

You might want to show a dialog saying processing and not show the grid till all is done. You might want to look at the DBGrid.BegingUpdate() and DBGrid.EndUPdate() if memory serve me right.

Comment: That stops the flicker but shows no change in the grid at all, then shows them all responses at once. That's what I had before but felt it left the user wondering what was happening. Thats why I displayed each response as it was found. If there's no other way I guess I could do it that way and have a progress bar. Personally though I don't like software that just shows a progress bar. Its nice to have reassurance that something has happened by showing results as you get them.

Comment: Users are used to progress bars indicating things are happening. They dont need to know the details.

Comment: Yes, possibly you are right, however I'll wait a bit to see if Peter will explain how to code his alternative to application.messages. Gone midnight here, I'll check again in morning!

Comment: There are no BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods for TDBGrid.

Comment: +tdiop like I said its been a looong time since I even looked at Delphi code. Shame really it used to be a great product.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use progress bar with progressbar1.repaint; in the loop to refresh just progress, instead of application.processmessages;

Answer (score 0):

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  MyQuery1.Edit;
  MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := '';
  MyQuery1.Next;
end;
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls; 

DBGrid1.RefreshData; 
Application.ProcessMessages;

 //For each row, check FieldA on the web and show response
MyQuery1.First;
while not MyQuery1.Eof do
begin
  DataToCheck := MyQuery1.FieldByName('FieldA').AsString ; //get data to check
  //get the web response and put into dataset
  MyQuery1.Edit;
  MyQuery1.FieldByName('web_response').AsString := GetWebCheckResponse(DataToCheck);
  MyQuery1.Next;

  DBGrid1.RefreshData;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Cheers,
Pham

Comment: Hi, can you explain what does your code do? your answer could be improved and it will become a good answer for future users too...